# use @std/esm to use ES6 in Express node.js project

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a Node.js project. I'm trying to use ES6 feature (like "import", "export") with a new ESM library but I'm struggling how to use it in Express app.

Here is what I have done:

1. Run `npm i --save @std/esm` in the project directory.
2. In index.js add "`require("@std/esm")`" to first line

use ESS "import"

here is my index.js

```
require("@std/esm")
// const express = require( "express" );
import express from '../node_modules/express'
const router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.get( "/", ( req, res, next ) => {
    res.render( "index", { "title": "Express" } );
} );
// export default router
module.exports = router;
```

Run the project but I get this error

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Volumes/Elements/Learning/Node/Project/NodeMongoTest1/routes/index.js
/Volumes/Elements/Learning/Node/Project/NodeMongoTest1/routes/index.js:3
import express from '../node_modules/express'
^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
        at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
        at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:626:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:703:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any know how to config ESM with Express Node.js?

Comment: import express from '../node_modules/express', doing import/require with node_modules path in it is sin

Comment: @theAnubhav hi can give a bit more detail how to correct? Thanks

Comment: by the way. I'm using webstorm and the template given by the IDE

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to enable ESM with @std/esm.

Enable ESM with a CJS bridge:
index.js

```
// Provide options as a parameter, environment variable, or rc file.
require = require("@std/esm")(module/*, options*/)
module.exports = require("./main.mjs").default
```

2. Enable ESM in the Node CLI with the -r option:

   node -r @std/esm main.mjs
3. Enable ESM in the Node REPL:

   node -r @std/esm

Try #2 first to check whether rest of code is correct in index file

Comment: The answer is pasted from README without attribution.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can you explain a bit detail on the step to configure with IDE? for example Webstorm?